# PHP CONSULTAS ERROR TIEMPO DE EJECUCIÓN

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Estoy realizando una consulta con CodeIgniter a sql server, mi problema es que cuándo hace consultas que pueden durar más de un minuto este me retorna null(no manda ningún error más que eso null).
Sin embargo consultas que duran menos de un minuto si las realiza y me manda los datos.
Ya leí que le tengo que modificar en PHP.ini
Max_input_time a más de 60
Max_execute_content a más de 60
Así que ya lo modifiqué
También agregue en el modelo la función de PHP el set_time_limit

Y nada ..

Lo raro es que en mi servidor local no importa que tarde más de un minuto, si lo hace.
Ya el problema es en el servidor web

Comment: hola te soy sincero ... estas segura que es `sql-server` y no `mysql`???

Comment: Totalmente segura. Jaja

Comment: acabo de agregar una respuesta fijate si te funciona ... la verdad los servidores en entorno de desarrollo son muy modestos en sus instalacion y aveces requerimos de mas recursos ....

Comment: En un entorno de producción, también los servidores web, tienen configurados cortafuegos, por ende, no solo hay que observar los parámetros de php y apache, sino del mismo cortafuegos, como puede ser alguna regla de WAF

Comment: Cierto, buscaré una solución para ello haber si se trata del cortafuegos

Comment: Pues en el servidor ejecute el comando del estado del firewall y aparece como not running así que con ello se descarta que sea problema del firewall¿no?

Comment: en teoria si, lo otro que toca hacer es buscar en los logs... hay dice cual es el error que rompio la ejecucion ....

Comment: Caray sigue sin arrojarme ningún error más que null, aún poniendo $this->db->error(), analizando ahorita, la única diferencia que veo es que mi local usa el drive sqlsrv y en producción usa mssql. No sé si algo tenga que ver

Comment: ¿qué haces en la DB que tarda más de 1 minuto?

Comment: Una consulta que por la cantidad de registros que hay en la bd y la forma en que se busca con el where hace que la consulta se tarde hasta 2 minutos.

Comment: Menciono que en mi local si me manda resultados pero ya en producción me manda null, ahorita a la conclusión que llegue porque no veo de otra, es por los drivers que manejo en el local manejo el driver sqlsrv y en producción maneja mssql

Comment: puede ser un problema en el query ....

Comment: o un limite en el mysql...

Comment: deberias agregar mas informacion sobre la configuracion y el log de errores de los 2 3 sistema: apache, php, sql-server

Comment: Gracias a todos ya encontré una solución :)

Comment: Al parecer La librería que maneja CodeIgniter 2 'mssql'. Es la que provoca que se corte la consulta al minuto. Debido a que no puedo ajustar la versión de CodeIgniter a una más nueva para hacer uso de su otra librería "sqlsrv" tuve que hacer uso de otra librería adodb que se ajuste a esta versión y todo funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue la siguiente
Al parecer La librería que maneja CodeIgniter 2 'mssql'. Es la que provoca que se corte la consulta al minuto. Debido a que no puedo ajustar la versión de CodeIgniter a una más nueva para hacer uso de su otra librería "sqlsrv" tuve que hacer uso de otra librería adodb que se ajuste a esta versión y todo funcionó